# How can i strip shortcode from HTML title tag?

Tags: shortcode

On a website, I am using Wordpress shortcodes for French example words: `[ex]beau[/ex]` becomes `<span class="ex" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">beau</span>`.

I would like to use the shortcode also in the title of a page/post. `add_filter( 'the_title', 'do_shortcode' );` in the functions.php works almost perfectly, but the HTML title tag includes `[ex]beau[/ex]` now.

I am looking for a way to use a shortcode in the title of page/post (`<?php the_title() ?>` in my page.php), but it should not appear in the HTML title tag (`<?php single_post_title(); ?>` in my header.php).

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function [`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) does the magic:

`<title><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_title()); ?></title>`